# Automatic Functions between 2 sets of Data

Tags: excel, statistics

In Excel, I have a column of x values and a column of y values. I need to multiply the x and y values together but I have 100 sets of values. How can I create a formula that will do this to all the data? 
Thank you.

Comment: Look into the `SUMPRODUCT` function which does exactly what you describe.

Comment: Please add screenshots of your input data and your desired output

Answer (score 1):

If you want a column of the results you need to use a multi-cell array formula.

Select all the cells you want the result (for example D1:D10) and type `=A1:A10*B1:B10` in the formula bar, then enter using ***`CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`*** rather than just enter.

If you want a single cell with the sum of the multiplication just enter as an ordinary formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10,B1:B10)
```